# Flask SQLAlchemy does not close MySQL database connections

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask app using Flask-SQLAlchemy with a MySQL database where the db is defined as the following:

`db.py`:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

`main.py`:

```
from db import db
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+pymysql://" + \
        DB_USERNAME + ":" + DB_PASSWORD + "@" + DB_HOST + "/" + DB_DATABASE
db.init_app(app)

@app.teardown_appcontext
def teardown_db(error):
    db.session.close()
    db.engine.dispose()
```

`user.py`:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

I query my database using models using either `db.engine.execute()` to write raw SQL queries where required or use the integrated Flask-SQLAlchemy APIs for reading data such as `User.query.filter_by().all()`.

I write new data into the db using the following:

```
new_user_entry = User(username = "abc", email = "abc@example.com")
db.session.add(new_user_entry)
db.session.commit()
```

I am monitoring my MySQL server using `show processlist` and I notice that the database connections keep increasing by 2 for every single request that comes my way. The database connections seem to reset only when I stop the Flask process. With time, the MySQL server throws the below error:

```
`sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 10 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/3o7r)`
```

I am serving the app using gunicorn and gevent/eventlet with 2 worker processes. I use python3.

Am I missing something here? I tried ending the db session and disposing the engine, but this does not seem to work.

Comment: How do you query database ? Please post that...

Comment: Check the [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that is launched in a background process. It might be still using sessions connected to the database and not release them.

I have very little experience with Flask though, but general rule of thumb (what ever the programming language or framework) - try to re-use/share  connections between sessions.

Comment: @DinkoPehar updated the question with the various ways I access the database.

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about this, I thought you don't session.commit() . Maybe this will help http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#storing-data. Good luck

Comment: @DinkoPehar I tried the solution that was provided but I could not circumvent `db.init_app(app)` being initialized.

Comment: I'm don't know more, but check eventlet/gevent, if you have 2 workers, do they commit all transactions, or set timeout on them http://eventlet.net/doc/basic_usage.html#eventlet.Timeout.
I think one worker doesn't commit and realease resources...

Comment: Interestingly, I notice the connection accumulation even when I use a development version (no gunicorn or gevent/eventlet).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found a fix to the above problem.

I used the declarative model defined in [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/sqlalchemy/#declarative) instead of following the quickstart documentation for Flask-SQLAlchemy given [here](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/).

The changed files are as follows:

`db.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine(DB_URI, convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_db():
    import user
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

`main.py`:

```
from db import init_db, db_session

init_db()

@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
    db_session.remove()
```

`user.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from data_models.db import Base
class User(Base):
    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

To query for records we could either use `User.query.filter_by().all()` or `db_engine.execute()`.

To write new data into the database, we can use the following:

```
new_user_entry = User(username = "abc", email = "abc@example.com")
db_session.add(new_user_entry)
db_session.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

In case we need to close session before creating a new child process (what is recommended), this is what we should use:

```
db.session.remove()
db.engine.dispose()
```

Like

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from app import db

@app.route('/process/start/', methods = ["GET"])
def process_start():
    db.session.remove()
    db.engine.dispose()
    p = Process(target = long_task)
    p.start()
    return 'started the long task'

def long_task():
    '''
    do long task
    '''
```

Answer (score 0):

Use with statement, there is a test:

```
def test():
    with db.session() as dbss:
        qss = models.WhateverModel.query.session
        assert dbss == qss
```